# Join 3 Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

I have 3 Data Extensions (Data Tables)

```
Subscription

CustomerInfo

Survey
```

All three tables have CustomerId as field.

Below is my Criteria:

> 1. Check for B13 or B26 in Benfitids of Subscripton
> 2. EmailOptin is True in CustomerInfo
> 3. CreateDt in Subscription should be over 30 days and
> 4. they are in Survey Table with the following conditions:
>
> QuestionId= ‘purchaseIntentQuestion’ and AnswerId = '3'
>       OR
>       QuestionId='goldenQuestion' AND (AnswerId = '1' OR AnswerId = '2')

Make sure that you have no duplicate records for Customerids

I wrote the below query but it is not returning results as expected. Pls advise

```
SELECT distinct sub.*, Cus.EmailOptin, srv.QuestionID,srv.AnswerId
FROM [Subscription] sub
JOIN [Survey Questions] srv ON sub.CustomerId = srv.CustomerId
JOIN [CustomerInfo] cus ON sub.CustomerId = cus.CustomerId
WHERE 1 = 1
AND CAST(sub.CreateDt AS DATE) < CAST(GETDATE() -30 AS DATE)
AND Cus.EmailOptin  = 'True'
AND 
(
sub.BenefitIds LIKE '%B13%'
OR
sub.BenefitIds LIKE '%B26%'
)
AND 
(
(srv.QuestionId = 'purchaseIntentQuestion' AND srv.AnswerId = '3')
OR 
(srv.QuestionId = 'goldenQuestion' AND (srv.AnswerId = '1' OR srv.AnswerId = '2' ))
)
```

For the above query even EmailOptin is not coming as True.
Pls advise.

Comment: I'd advise against using `select sub.*`.  SFMC caches column names, so if a column is added to `[subscription]`, your query won't select it.

Comment: Please post the details about your Data Extension columns (data types, precisions, etc.).  Your question is about invalid column values and you've provided no details about them.  For example, is `Customer.EmailOptin` a Boolean field or Text?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs, EmailOptin is Boolean.
The question was solved later. The same query worked by a bit of tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your arguments first in your WHERE clause one by one - since I can't see your data I'm not sure what those arguments are.

Also, I seem to remember marketing cloud not liking wildcard SELECTS when also using a JOIN. You may have to call out each individual field.